# cache align elements of array

Tags: c, arrays, gcc

Is there a way to force each element of an array to be cache-aligned without having to add padding to the end of each array element, or to the type itself?

So if I had:

```
struct foo {
    struct bar bar;
}; 

struct foo fooarray[100] __attribute__((aligned(CACHE_LINE_SIZE)));
```

This will declare an array fooarray, where the array itself is cache aligned, but the individual elements are not (so `fooarray[1]` is not on a cache line).   The structure itself is used outside of the array, and therefore I'd prefer not to automatically add padding to it.  At the same time I'd prefer not to have to do any extra casting/dereferences when I access the elements of the array...

Comment: You only care about gcc? (Or about gcc on a particular platform)? Because there is no *portable* way to do this.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without padding.Either "automatic" or "manual".

Comment: Assume `CACHE_LINE_SIZE` is already known  (I am primarily interested in gcc, but am curious in general...)

Comment: OK. In general, there is no guarantee that you can use an alignment declaration to force an alignment more stringent than that of the most stringently-aligned basic type. GCC allows more stringent alignments, but they will not be portable. If you want every element to be aligned, declare the element as having an alignment, not the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to force each element of an array to be cache-aligned without having to add padding to the end of each array element, or to the type itself?

No, there is not.  The representation of an array is defined to be a *contiguous* series of representations of its elements.  You can align the start of the array, and hence its first element, but if the array has more than one element, and the element size is not divisible by the cache line size then some of the elements must fail to be cache-aligned.

Comment: Ok thanks.   That had occured to me as I was typing up the question, but I thought I would ask anyways in case there was something I didn't know.